# Understanding WooCommerce Build-In Geolocation/ Geo_IP classes

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, geo-data

I would like to show/hide a fee in the WooCommerce checkout process depending on the location of the user.

For this i would like to first use the IP address of the user to determine the location and later the address he enters.

I came across the build-in Geolocation ability of WooCommerce with the following classes:

- WC_Geo_IP (https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Geo_IP.html)
- WC_Geo_IP_Record (https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Geo_IP_Record.html)
- WC_Geolocation (https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Geolocation.html)

I'm able to get the users IP address with:

```
$geolocation = new WC_Geolocation();
$ipaddress = $geolocation->get_ip_address();
```

But i don't seem to be able to get the users country code. How would i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used WooCommerce to get the country code on a recent project, using the `geolocate_ip` method of  the `WC_Geolocation` class.

```
$country = 'US';

if (class_exists('WC_Geolocation')) {
    $location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip('', true, false);

    if (isset($location['country'])) {
        $country = $location['country'];
    }
}

switch ($country) {
    case 'AU':
        break;
    case 'US':
        break:
}
```